# Headline next to page number overtaken to next chapter

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I have one chapter for my listings

```
%%% Document Class
\documentclass[ngerman,bt]{dbvdoc}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings 
\cleardoublepage
```

and the next one for the acronyms

```
\chapter*{Acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
    ....
\end{acronym}
```

The problem is that the headline which reads next to the page number (I don't know how to call it) on the second page of the acronyms chapter is still "Listings", I dont know how to change it. I'm using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: Add the line `\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}` next to the `\addcontentsline`. Is the `dbvdoc` class accessible for checking whether there's a better way?

Comment: it works, thank you egreg! I honestly don´t know.

Answer (score 3):

The headlines can be set manually with

```
\chapter*{Acronyms}
\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
```

possibly with some formatting to make them agree with the other headlines.

If the class is `book` or is based on book, one could simply say

```
\chapter{Acronyms}
```

provided this is between the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` declarations.